# WordPress/Woo - Showing Users' purchased orders from only defined category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode

I am displaying Users' purchased products with the below shortcode, but I need it to only show products from a certain defined category, not every product, help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```html
add_shortcode( 'my_purchased_products', 'bbloomer_products_bought_by_curr_user' );
   
function bbloomer_products_bought_by_curr_user() {
   
    // GET CURR USER
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) return;
   
    // GET USER ORDERS (COMPLETED + PROCESSING)
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_is_paid_statuses() ),
    ) );
   
    // LOOP THROUGH ORDERS AND GET PRODUCT IDS
    if ( ! $customer_orders ) return;
    $product_ids = array();
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $customer_order->ID );
        $items = $order->get_items();
        foreach ( $items as $item ) {
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            $product_ids[] = $product_id;
        }
    }
    $product_ids = array_unique( $product_ids );
    $product_ids_str = implode( ",", $product_ids );
   
    // PASS PRODUCT IDS TO PRODUCTS SHORTCODE
    return do_shortcode("[products ids='$product_ids_str']");
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple condition for your `$items` foreach loop should do it. Change this:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $product_ids[] = $product_id;
}
```

To this:

```
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    if( has_term( array( 'one-category', 'another-category' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        $product_ids[] = $product_id;
    }
}
```

The code only displays products that belong to `one-category` or `another-category` product cats. You can define one product category slug, or as many as you need.

Comment: Hey, thanks heaps for the help, looks great, just WordPress is throwing out this error:


```" Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 159 of file wp-content/themes/kadence-child/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

syntax error, unexpected ';' "``` 

& this is the final code:

```foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    if( has_term( array( 'one-category', 'another-category' ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) {
        $product_ids[] = $product_id;
    }
}```

Comment: @ZeonTimar Sorry, I had a typo in my code (missing bracket in if condition). Please use the updated code above.

Comment: Thanks again that's great, it instantly worked just as described, I really appreciate your time. Only thing now is when I change the Category to another, it seems to show all products even ones the User has not purchased, much appreciated.

Comment: Hey nevermind that mate! It seems to work perfect now, thanks again for your efforts it is very appreciated.